# java, input double value by scanner method, number with decimal return error

Tags: java

As a java newbie, I wrote down this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EserciziCap2_6_2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner aaa = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("inserire x");
        Double x = aaa.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

It works fine with no decimal value like for 4 it returns 4.0, for 2 it returns 2.0 and so on.
but , if I type let's say 1.14 it returns below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2564)
at EserciziCap2_6_2.main(EserciziCap2_6_2.java:8)
```

What 's wrong?

Comment: ...enter `1,14` instead of `1.14`

Comment: It works fine for me, as expected..you sure something else is not the problem?

Comment: hello everyone, thank you for answers. YCF_L tip works. i can't use replace method because it seems not being available in my eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

You have to enter "," instead of ".".
If you want to use "." as the comma use:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner aaa = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("inserire x");
    String input = aaa.nextLine().replace(".", ",");
    Double x = Double.parseDouble(input);
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I really dont know, in which case it will end up with "a lot of commas". A valid double only has one comma.

Comment: Wait a minute. Gonna  test that.

Comment: Thanks for telling me. Gonna change it to replace.